# How can I use 2 models in a single view?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, models

I'm currently working on a homepage where I am showing the 'latest hauls' and 'latest finds' they are both separate models ofcourse.

Currently I am only showing the 5 latest hauls since I use the `HaulController@getWelcome` Controller so I can access `$haul->title` etc.

How would I be able to also access `$finds->title`?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You'd adjust `getWelcome` to pass both variables to the view.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes! That worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can share a model to a view by using it inside controller function -

```
View::share('subadmin', App\Models\SubAdmin::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the model in your view like
`{{ \App\Model::function() }}`
 So you can have `{{ App\Model::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(5)->get() }}`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

Option 1:  A combined model and one view.
To do this create a new ViewModel and have LatestHauls and LatestFinds as properties on this model.  You could set these properties in the controller.
On your view simply navigate down the viewmodel to the appropriate properties.

Option 2: Extend the above solution to use partial views.  Create a partial view for each model.  On the parent view call each partial view.  This might be considered a better solution but option 1 will get you started.